# Testing Squid performance (kerberos authentication)

Tags: proxy, performance-testing, kerberos, squid

Im trying to test our organizations proxy server, which uses kerberos authentication. We have found previous problems, that proxy can overwhelm kerberos authentication and fail to provide authorization.

Any suggestions, what tools (free) I can use, to test this?

P.S. Its plain kerberos, no NTML.

I tried jmeter, but looks like it accesses kerberos authentication directly, which avoids the task Im trying to achieve.

Comment: Kerberos is supposed to be used in the context of a **session**, not in a pure stateless REST way! Also, it was designed for point-to-point auth, hence workarounds are necessary for distributed systems or load balancers. For instance, the Hadoop stack (UIs and REST APIs alike) use SPNego only on the 1st HTTP call, and send back a "signed cookie" that is used for authentication in later calls. And the cookie contains a shared cluster-wide token, hence it does not require sticky sessions .

Comment: PS: _"plain Kerberos"_ sounds like a joke, given the complexity of that protocol (somewhat masked by the billions of $ that Microsoft spent in back-porting Kerberos into its AD and Windows stacks, when it became clear that NTLM was just too naive and too vulnerable for corporate usage)